# How do i forcibly process messages inside a thread?

Tags: delphi, winsock

Despite having Application.ProcessMessages, which is only for the Main VCL Thread, is there a similiar method for a TThread class ? or how can i write one on my own ?

lets say that on the client side i use SendBuf 2 times...

```
SendBuf(....
SendBuf(....
```

on server side, OnRead gets fired 2 times, but between us i have already read the socket buffer in a single OnRead call, so how do i avoid the 2nd one without exceptions ? the only way i can think of is process the messages in the message queue so they'd get out of there already and won't fire that event again. (do it while reading)

Comment: This sounds more like a problem to do with the communication protocol and not really anything to do with threads.  If you use `SendBuf` twice then presumably you are sending two commands or instructions.  If each is terminated with an appropriate termination character then each `OnRead` should read only one of the instructions in the buffer.  It sounds like what is needed is a data packet implementation more than anything.

Comment: Yeah, it's usually the core component that i blame, but hey, i don't want to modify the unit.pas and probably ruin something, so i'm trying to bypass/solve this issue on my side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to process messages in a worker thread, you have to run a message loop manually, eg:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  ...
  while GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0 then
  begin
    TranslateMessage(Msg);
    DispatchMessage(Msg);
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  ...
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ...
    if PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) then
    begin
      TranslateMessage(Msg);
      DispatchMessage(Msg);
    end;
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  ...
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    ...
    if MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, nil, FALSE, SomeTimeout, QS_ALLINPUT) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
    begin
      while PeekMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) do
      begin
        TranslateMessage(Msg);
        DispatchMessage(Msg);
      end;
    end;
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Not like that, i meant when i do some heavy work, i want to be able to process it through a function.

for example, inside the vcl thread, if i am inside a loop i can just do application.processmessages.

Comment: Your question asked "How do I process messages inside a thread?" My answer shows you how to do that. If that is not your real question, then you need to change your question.